# jQuery drag after appendTo

Tags: jquery, draggable, appendto

I found many examples about this but all were too complicated for what I need.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
  jQuery(".drag").click(function () { $(this).appendTo(".inner")});
  jQuery(".drag").draggable({ grid: [ 10, 10 ] }, { containment: ".inner" } );
});
```

I would like to drag the same element only after I append it to the container I wish.

Note that the drag elements are outside the container which I want them to drag. That's why I use the appendTo.

HTML:

```
...
    <div class="inner"></div>
    ...

    <div class="objects">
    <div class="drag"><img src="img1.jpg" title="name1" /></div>
    <div class="drag"><img src="img2.jpg" title="name2" /></div>
    <div class="drag"><img src="img3.jpg" title="name3" /></div>
    </div>
...
```

Comment: Could you add a little more detail, maybe also your html/css?

Comment: Yes, you 're right, I added the HTML information.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you trying to do, but jQuery UI event `start`may help you:

```
$(function() {
  jQuery(".drag").draggable({
      grid: [ 10, 10 ],
      containment: ".inner",
      start: function() { $("#result").html("Drag start!"); }
  } );
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="inner">
    Inner div

<div class="drag">
</div>
</div>
<p id="result"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div { border:1px solid black; padding:5px; }
.inner { width: 200px; height:200px; }
.drag { width:50px; height: 50px; background-color:#fca;}​
```

​

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpoussel/fxfbD/).

Comment: Post your code in your answer too. (The idea is the answer is self contained and won't die if JSFiddle goes off the grid)